# Simple JavaScript Slider - Need some OOP help to make it work

Tags: javascript, oop, slider

Im in the process of creating my own slider library with pure JavaScript. Have a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/bingo14/bhymxrqr/1/

Im trying to return the latest 'currentValue' from the getValue() function, but its returning 0 as you can see from the initial alert.

```
this.getValue = function getValue() {
//how do I return the latest current value?   
return currentValue;
};
```

How can I make this get updated every time the user moves the slider? I think I need some help with OOP principles here!

Thanks.

Comment: It does update, I added `setInterval(function() {console.log(mySlider.getValue()) }, 1000);` and every second the current value is returned

Comment: To start of, If you're building a plugin/library you might want to consider to use an `input` element [and all it's benefits (in term of available attributes)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) - instead of a DIV

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan - What kind of JS design pattern would you use here?

Comment: @bingo14 the one that gives flexibility and expandability to the user. (Too long to write in comment) Really, you should consider that most users use that kind of elements inside forms where they expect the element's `value` (means it's an input) to be sent on form submit

Comment: @bingo14 you have lots of available patterns to start from, you just need to carefully pick the right one depending on the software design.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan - Ah yeah, it should be an input element so that it can be submitted! I am following the module pattern: https://carldanley.com/js-module-pattern/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It does update, I added setInterval(function() {console.log(mySlider.getValue()) }, 1000); and every second the current value is returned"

I wasnt testing it properly! Alex K. got it right